# Updating SQlite version in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6

I'm new to iOS, However, I know in Android, if you change table structure of SQLLite DB from old version of your app to another. Than I need to change something called **" DATABASE_VERSION"** so that old tables will be dropped and new tables will be created.

How to do the same in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS' version of SQLite (the actual SQLite lib) does not have that covenience.  To keep track of a database version, SQLite provides a benign field called `PRAGMA user_version`, which you can manually `UPDATE`, but it doesn't trigger a database upgrade like Android does.  Instead, you have to either `DROP TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE` yourself.

Comment: Oops.  Don't touch `schema_version`, or you'll break SQL.

Comment: Thanks ... do you have any link for an example that show how PRAGMA user_version works?

Comment: Literally "PRAGMA user_version = 1".